# import function changing its implicit variable

Tags: python, function, import, global-variables

How do I call an object of an imported function, changing a global variable inside the function?

Example:

on func.py

```
a = 2
def f(x):
    f = a*x**2
    return f
```

on deriv.py

```
def df(f, x, h):
    return (f(x + h) - f(x-h)) / (2*h)
```

on main.py

```
from deriv import df
from func import f

res = df( f, 2 , 0.0001  )

print(res)
```

This works for `a=2`. Is there a way to change the value of `a` on main.py? So I could calculate the derivative of function `f = a*x**2` with an arbitrary `a` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this too (perhaps not a good style though).

```py
from deriv import df
from func import f
import func
func.a = 0

res = df( f, 2 , 0.0001  )

print(res)
```

Comment: @Leo you shouldn't do this, instead, `f` should take `a` as a parameter

Comment: @junpa.arrivillaga Right. Importing `a` is not necessary (deleted). 
I myself don't think this is a good design either.  But the OP was wondering if this is ever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value of `a` in the function as a parameter.

```
def f(x,a=2):
    f = a*x**2
    return f
```

Comment: But how could I change on main program the value of 'a' ?

Comment: @Leo `df` should take `a` as a parameter, and pass it to `f`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, understood the answer now. But I needed to change both `f` and `df` (not a problem). It worked and the looks a cleaner solution. I'll follow this one then. Thanks.